# What is the difference between Model3DCollection and Model3DGroup?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm  a new guy in the 3D programming over WPF, I have been reading the documentation about the .NET framework elements that allows to create a 3D environment. I came across this question: What is the difference between [Model3DCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.model3dcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Model3DGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Model3DGroup(v=vs.110).aspx)?

The documentation states that the `Model3DGroup`

> Enables using a number of 3-D models as a unit.

and the `Model3DCollection`

> Represents an ordered collection of Model3D objects.

As far as I can tell both of them work in a similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Model3DGroup` is a `Model3D` and can be used in places that require a `Model3D`. It has other features as well such as freezing.

The collection type is nothing more than a collection.

Comment: I downvoted, because this hardly qualifies as an answer. You should have elaborated on what the difference is, and when one should be used instead of another.